# how to redirect to a page in django

Tags: django

I am creating a webapp where i have sections like home,profile,and on home page there are several posts which are written by users. But when i go to the posts and from there if i have to return back to home page,it says page not found. it takes me to the following link `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/4/home`. but i want to go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home`. How to do this

```
<li> <a href="profile">Profile </a></li>
            <li> <a href="logout">Logout</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="password_change">Password change</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="home">home </a>
</li>
```

my views.py of homepage

```
def homep(request):
    context = {
        'posts':post.objects.all()
    }
    return render (request,'welcome.html',context)
```

my urls.py

```
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    path('login',views.login_view,name='login'),
    path('register',views.register,name="Login now"),
    path('logout',views.logout_view,name='logout'),
    path('profile', views.profile,name='profile'),
    path('home',PostListView.as_view(),name='home'),
    path('edit_profile',views.profile_change,name='profile_change'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/',PostDetailView.as_view(),name ='post-detail'),
```

Comment: Have you tried using `href={% url 'home' %}` instead of `href="home"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good practice to hardcode html links in the href , You can use Django template tags, for example

```
<a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
```

where home is the name given in the urls.py file
[for more info you can check here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

where you can also send id's like

```
<a href="{% url 'post' post.id %}">Post</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because it will each time append the values at the end. You can prevent that by prepending a slash, so `href="/logout"`, but probably it is better to make use of the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

```
<li><a href="{% url 'profile' %}">Profile </a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'password_change' %}">Password change</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">home</a></li>
```